# difference between 2 structures types in perl

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between the following structures in Perl:

```
$VAR = {"user" => "text", "id" => "textid"};

$VAR = {"user" : 4, "code" : "codetext"};
```

And how can I access the values of each structure?

Comment: What made you think `$VAR = {"user" : 4, "code" : "codetext"};` is valid Perl? I don't see the sense of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is a hash reference with two *keys* inside.

```
$VAR = {"user" => "text", "id" => "textid"};
```

You access it with the dereferencing operator `->` or by using the `${ ... }` syntax. Because it's only one level deep, the `{}` can be omitted.

```
my $id   = $VAR->{id};    # textid
my $user = $$VAR{user}; # text
```

Read more about it in [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

---

The second one is not valid Perl syntax. It looks like it's JSON. Maybe it was not deserialized yet?

Use the [JSON module](http://p3rl.org/JSON) to deserialize it and you will end up with the first one.

```
use JSON 'decode_json';

#         'note the quotes'
my $VAR = '{"user" : 4, "code" : "codetext"}';
my $perl_data_structure = decode_json($VAR);
my $user = $perl_data_structure->{user};
```

Comment: after i deserialize the second...i can access "user"..my $user = $foo->{user}?

Comment: @tsiro yes, exactly. That will turn it into a Perl data structure.

Answer (score 5):

```
$VAR = {"user" => "text", "id" => "textid"};
```

Here $VAR is a hash reference which contains 2 keys (`user` and `id`) whose values are `text` and `textid` respectively.

Accessing hashref data

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $hashref = {"user" => "text", "id" => "textid"};
foreach my $key (keys %$hashref){
    print "Key: $key and Value: $hashref->{$key}";  
}
```

---

```
$VAR = {"user" : 4, "code" : "codetext"};
```

This is not a valid syntax, you will get error if you `use strict; use warnings;`. I think this is a dump of JSON data. If that's the case you'll need to parse JSON using available [JSON modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=json&mode=all) on CPAN. [simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33144965/257635) has shown you how to parse JSON using [JSON module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

Comment: Heh! It's very rare to beat you to it :P